# How can I parse csv to array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I want to parse csv file to array. But I have a problem. I get csv file name,but when I do parse this parth return me this error.
'The provided file test.csv doesn't exists or inaccessible'
How can I resolve this problem?

```
const csv = require('csv-array');

router.post('/upload', function(req,res){
   let test = req.files.test.name //this return me uploaded file name
   csv.parseCSV(test, (data) => {
      console.log(data); //this parth return me 'The provided file 
                                     //test.csv doesn't exists or inaccessible'
   })
})
```

Comment: I think the path doesn't exist. It's looking for test.csv in your file system. And you have the file in memory, not disk. What I would do is see if csv-array can take a stream or byte array as a file and then get the file from your request in that format.  I recommend busboy.

Comment: Seems like if you're using Express then according to this, https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload, req.files.test.data should get you the file buffer. Not sure if you need to decode from base-64 or not yourself but try passing that buffer into the appropriate csv-array function

Answer (score 0):

Your [csv-array package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-array)'s parseCSV method expects the first argument to be a filename. You should tell us what the `console.log(req.files.test.name)` is.

Assuming it is exactly "test.csv", your error is obvious, as you mentioned:

```
The provided file test.csv doesn't exists or inaccessible
```

(1) Make sure that file actually exists wherever your script is running from

(2) If that does indeed exist (and you are pointing to the right location), verify its permissions. You might need to grant read permission for whoever is executing the application.